# Interface in TypeScript

Tags: typescript

I am reading Typescript handbook， in the chapter of interface, I found a question:

```
interface LabelledValue {
  label: string;
}

function printLabel(labelledObj: LabelledValue) {
  console.log(labelledObj.label);
}

let myObj = {size: 10, label: "Size 10 Object"};
printLabel(myObj);
```

The `printLabel` need an object with a `label:string` property， but the object we passed has another property called `size`. It is OK cause the compiler only checks that at least the ones required are present and match the types required.

But, we I call `printLabel` in this way:

```
printLabel({size: 10, label: "Size 10 Object"});
```

The compile throws an exception.

so why?

Comment: Can you include the exception?

Comment: If you'd search for the error message (`object literal may only specify known properties`) you'll find the answers: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31816061/why-am-i-getting-an-error-object-literal-may-only-specify-known-properties or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32897098/typescript-object-implementing-interface-with-extra-properties-error

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The documentation is outdated and [an issue exists to fix it](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript-Handbook/issues/139).

From the [What's New in TypeScript page](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/What%27s-new-in-TypeScript#stricter-object-literal-assignment-checks):

> TypeScript 1.6 enforces stricter object literal assignment checks for the purpose of catching excess or misspelled properties. Specifically, when a fresh object literal is assigned to a variable or passed as an argument for a non-empty target type, it is an error for the object literal to specify properties that don't exist in the target type.

The idea is that it's a very common pattern is to pass in an object literal as a bag of options. For instance:

```
interface ConnectionOptions {
    tryHttps?: boolean;
    url?: string;
    username?: string;
    password?: string;
}
```

But all of those properties are optional. Before 1.6, I could misspell any of them and the compiler would never catch this error:

```
declare function connect(options: ConnectionOptions);

// Notice the property given is 'tryHTTPS' instead of 'tryHttps'.
connect({ url: "stackoverflow.com", tryHTTPS: true });
```

You can always get around this by adding a type assertion to the type you're assigning to:

```
printLabel({size: 10, label: "Size 10 Object"} as LabelledValue);
// or...
printLabel(<LabelledValue>{size: 10, label: "Size 10 Object"});
```